# How can I find the mean of three rasters?

Tags: r, spatial, raster

I have three dataframes, for which I am trying to find a cell-by-cell mean.

```
r1<-raster('a.tif')
r2<-raster('b.tif')
r3<-raster('c.tif')
```

However, doing this is giving me the following error

```
q<-mean(r1,r2,r3)
```

or

```
q<-(r1+r2+r3)/3
```

Error

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : options(warn) not set
Warning message:
closing unused connection 4 .....
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that works. But how can I use it with q<-(r1+r2+r3)/3? Because I would be doing more extensive calculations with different formulae..

Comment: `q <- mean(r1,r2,r3)` and `q<-(r1+r2+r3)/3` works for me. The error message is related to connection. Problem of raster version? Mine is `2.4-22`.

Comment: Thanks. I have an aside question if you don't mind. I have thousands of rasters with same resolution and extent (r1,r2,r10000 etc.). Is it advisable to stack all of them for operations? Or should I continue individually like using q<-(r1+r2+r3)/3? Thanks.

Comment: For curiosity, what is the output of `options("warn")`?

Comment: $warn
[1] 0             

.Also, how are you getting 2.4-22. Mine is latest and that is 2.4-20. R is now getting any latest version automatically. On windows. Latest R as well.

Comment: I think it works now. Not sure what is happening. The error is not consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a weird error message. Often this type of situation goes away if you restart R *without* loading an old workspace (which may be stale). If that is what is going on use `unlink(".RData")`, exit R without saving and start again.

To answer your aside question, yes it is much easier to stack them. E.g.

```
f <- list.files(pattern='tif$')
s <- stack(f)
x <- sum(s)
```